# Shopping cart won't work and I want to cry

Tags: python, django, shopping-cart

Trying to build a shopping cart app for a job interview.  It's due in a few hours and I can't get it to work.

Any suggestions would be helpful--here's the product view that does the heavy lifting:

```
def products(request, store_subdomain):
    store_db, store_products = database_selector(store_subdomain)
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST': #load catalog page with "item added"
        product = store_products.get(pk=request.POST['product_id'])
        cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
        if cart.get(product):
            cart['product_id'] += 1
        else:
            cart['product_id'] = 1
        request.session['cart'] = cart
    request.session.modified = True
        return render_to_response('catalog.html', 
                {'store_name': store_db.name, 'store_products': store_products, 
                'message':'Item Added'}, context_instance=context)  
    return render_to_response('catalog.html', 
        {'store_name': store_db.name, 
        'store_products' : store_products}, context_instance=context)
```

And the relevant template portion that should add to the cart:

```
<form method="post" action="." class="cart">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <br />
    Qty <input type="number" name="qty" value = "1"> </br>
    <button type="submit" value="{{p.id}}" name= "product_id" />Add to Cart</button>
</form>
```

And the view which calls the cart:

```
def shoppingcart(request, store_subdomain):
    #load page of all shopping cart items
    store_db, store_products = database_selector(store_subdomain)
    return render_to_response('shoppingcart.html', 
            {'store_name': store_db.name, 
            'store_products': store_products, 
            'cart' : cart})
```

And the template which should display what's in the cart:

```
{% for p,k in cart %}
<div class="product_image" >
        <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/{{p.image}}" alt={{p.name}}/>      <br />
    </div>
    <h1><span property="v:name">{{ p.name }}</span></h1>
    <br />
    Price: {{ p.price|currency }} X Qty {{ k }} = 
{{cart}}
```

The Post method is definitely being triggered, but when I go to the shopping cart page (which should show all the products in it) it's empty.

Comment: Could you show the part of catalog.html for products list?

Answer (score 1):

Add following line after you set the `cart` in the request session.

```
...
request.session['cart'] = cart
request.session.modified = True
```

Default django behavior is it would not save `request.session` if any of its attribute is not changed, which is generally case when dict is stored.

More documentation at [When sessions are saved](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/?from=olddocs#when-sessions-are-saved)

Comment: I think my problem now is that the cart won't update.  I have five products in it, and no matter what I do those same products remain--can't add or subtract.

Comment: @thumbtackthief, In your `shoppingcart` view you haven't defined `cart` that is to be passed to template.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I would do that?  All this session work confuses me to no end.

Comment: @thumbtackthief, add line `request.session['cart'] = cart` in `shoppingcart()` view.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the template in a block since it's extending something. You can't just put that code in there after an {% extends %} tag and expect it to work.